# Swift - Function where parameter must conform to protocol and check is kindOf

Tags: swift, function, parameters, swift-protocols

I have an OrderBook with expected and completed orders; both of which are array of Ints.

I want to have an 'add' order function which is generic and works for both the expected and completed class;

Both classes follow a protocol.

I wish to make a function call where the object passed in must conform to a protocol; not only that I want to check that the order is `kindOf` class.

```
protocol EntryProtocol {
    var value: Int { get set }
}

class OrderBook {
    var existingOrders: [ExistingOrder] = [ExistingOrder]()
    var completedOrders: [CompletedOrder] = [CompletedOrder]()

    func add<C1: Any>(order: C1) where C1: EntryProtocol {

        print (order is ExistingOrder.Type) // returns false
        print (order is CompletedOrder.Type)  // returns false

        // i want to do a switch here
    }
}

class ExistingOrder: EntryProtocol {
    var value : Int

    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }

    // .. other methods
}



class CompletedOrder: EntryProtocol {
    var value : Int

    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }

    // .. other methods
}


var orderBook: OrderBook = OrderBook()

let howMany = 4

for _ in 1...howMany {
    let value = 3 // this is a random number (1-6)
    let order = ExistingOrder.init(value: value)
    orderBook.add(order: order)
}

print (orderBook.existingOrders)
print (orderBook.completedOrders)
```

In my swift playground, the add() function always returns false when I check to see whether it is a ExistingOrder or CompletedOrder

How do I make a function where the parameter must conform to a protocol; then check that the object passed in via parameter is of a certain type?

Many thanks

Comment: Shouldn't that be `order is ExistingOrder` (without the `.Type`)?

Comment: Remove the `.Type` from your `is` checks

Comment: Though since you're going to need to use the casted object to add it to your array you should probably be doing `if let order = order as? ExistingOrder` anyway

Comment: Oh, okay I will try this! - hey that works, many thanks all!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is to use `order is ExistingOrder`, crediting @rmaddy then check the return `if let order = order as? ExistingOrder`, crediting @dan